# Insert html element after count in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var num = parseInt($.trim($(this).text()));
$(this).html('<i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}"></i>', ++num);
```

After a certain div gets clicked the count must go up. This actually works but alongside with that an icon has to be added to the clicked div. How would I do this? The above sample work, but only the `<i>` gets inserted.

EDIT:
The `dataset-postid="{{ $post->id }}"` defines the post_id that has this like button. What has to be changed is `{{ $likes}}`

```

```
<div class="wis-numbers">
   <?php $likes = $post->likes->count() ?>
       <span id="like" class="like"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">
           <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}"></i> 
          {{ $likes }}
       </span>

 </div>
```

I tried to solve this with only updating text with Jquery, like this:

```
var num = parseInt($.trim($(this).text()));
$(this).text(++num);
```

But then this disappears from my html `<i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">`  So I have to include it somehow with the count.

This is my full AJAX/Jquery for this button, basically if the button ges clicked, the count must go up (or down if disliked) and a class 'active' needs to be added

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        postId = event.target.dataset['postid'];

        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");


            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlLike,
                data: { postId: postId, _token: token },
            });

            console.log('unlike');

        } else {

            $(this).addClass("active");

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlLike,
                data: { postId: postId, _token: token },
            });

            console.log('like');

        }
```

Comment: Only what gets inserted?

Comment: Your increment works but just because you can pass anything to any js method and it will be processed. BUT your code doesn't make sense, jq `html()` method doesn't accept any of this kind of argument. And i suppose `{{ $post->id }}` is for some kind of template engine. Why don't you use: `$(this).html('<i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="' + (++num) + '"></i>');`?  EDI>T: in fact, i'm really not sure what are you expecting. Posting only none working code without explaination doesn't really help to figure it out

Comment: Maybe: `$(this).html('<i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">' + (++num) + '</i>');`